# Special apostrophe breaks JSON

Tags: php, json, apostrophe, latin1

```
[7671] => Sleaford Carre’s
```

is an element in $result

```
$result=  json_encode($result);
echo $result;
//outputs
"7671":null,
```

Please note that this is not a normal apostrophe (single quote) or a back tick.
I cant even find it on my keyboard. Data comes from a Latin-1 table.

I have also noticed that using htmlentities on building the array will dissapear the string from the array. What am I to do??

Comment: have you tried to encode everything in UTF-8 first? This will solve many issues like this.

Comment: `json_encode()` expects UTF-8 encoded data.

Comment: I'd seriously look at transferring the data to a table that supports a modern encoding. Using 1990s legacy encodings is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Try to encode your string to UTF-8 first. Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php --- (utf8_encode function)

Comment: as the others have said, use utf8_encode() then json_encode().

Comment: using utf_encode() on building the array gives me `"7671":"Sleaford Carre\u0092s` That'll probably do it. thanks guys. Don't know how that data got entered!

Comment: Anyone want a green tick? I'll give you 10 mins. @quentin if I had a choice about legacy stuff, I wouldn't be using windows+sqlServer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As no-one has actually written an answer, read the comments:)

as the others have said, use utf8_encode() then json_encode(). –  Brian